# How can I skip an OS error so that my for-loop does not break?

Tags: python, function, loops, directory, try-catch

I have a function that successfully gets all the filepaths of a top folder. However, the loop breaks when it runs into a folder which I have no permission to access.

**How can I skip this error so that I can extract all the rest of the filepaths without breaking my loop?**

I was thinking of using `try` and `except` but I am unsure how to implement this. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
def get_list_of_files(dir_name):
    """
    Gets all the filepaths. 
    :param: dir_name: the name of the directory to parse 
    : return all of the filepaths 
    """
    list_files = os.listdir(dir_name)
    all_files = list()      
    
    for item in list_files:
        full_path = os.path.join(dir_name, item)
        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            all_files = all_files + get_list_of_files(full_path)
        else:
            all_files.append(full_path)
    return all_files
```

Comment: Please look up try/except block, that'll set you in the right direction

Comment: I wouldnt be asking this question without looking that up first of course. Would it work to implement 'try' at the top of the for loop, and except: OSError ?  cheers

Comment: Which statement breaks/gives the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below, basically, its using a "try, except", making the code "try" to execute as usual, and when he runs into OSError exception, he starts execute things under "except", which is in my sample, passes over to the next item in list_files.

```
list_files = os.listdir(dir_name)
all_files = list()      

for item in list_files:
    try:
        full_path = os.path.join(dir_name, item)
        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            all_files = all_files + get_list_of_files(full_path)
        else:
            all_files.append(full_path)
    except OSError:
        # maybe some other code you want to execute
        continue
return all_files
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [os.path.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), which seems to keep files/directories out you dont have permissions for and comes with builtin recursion:

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 foobar  wheel   128B Oct 14 14:25 .
drwxrwxrwt  15 root    wheel   480B Oct 14 14:30 ..
drwx------   2 root    wheel    64B Oct 14 14:25 bar
-rw-r--r--   1 foobar  wheel     0B Oct 14 14:25 foo.txt
```

... directory `bar` is just readable by the root user.

```
def get_list_of_files(dir_name):
    all_files = []
    for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(dir_name):
        for file in files:
            all_files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, file))
    return all_files

files = get_list_of_files('/tmp/test')
print(files)
```

Out:

```
['/tmp/test/foo.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `except OSError`.

This can get you on track:

```
for number in range(-1,3):
    try:
        print(1/number)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass
```

```
# -1.0
# notice how 0 is simply skipped because it gets caught by except
# 1.0
# 0.5
```

Following your mention that you are unsure how to implement it, one might think to put the whole `for loop` in the `try except` block resulting in:

```
try:
    for item in range(-1,3):
        print(1/item)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('This gets printed when the first error is caught and the loop stops')

# -1.0
# This gets printed when the first error is caught and the loop stops
```

Comment: OP has already mentioned that they know about try/except

Comment: OP stated that she/he is unsure how to implement it.

Comment: Using a bare ```except``` is never recommended